# PHP buttons to delete a row in MYSQL table output

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, delete-row

My goal is to display the entire table e.g SELECT * FROM athlete and include button for each row in the table output, that when pressed will remove that row from the database.

I have followed another post and shown below is what I have so far but does not work:

```
//if(isset($_POST['delete_id']) && (!empty($_POST['delete_id']))) 
if(isset($_POST['Delete'])){ 

$delete_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delete_id']); 
echo("deletebutton" . $delete_id);
//mysql_query("DELETE FROM KeepScores WHERE `id`=".$delete_id); 
//header('Location: main.php'); 
} 

else
{
$query = 'SELECT * FROM athlete';
$result = mysql_query($query);


$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$self = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // strip tags to improve security

echo("<table> 
<tr> 
<td> id </td> 
<td>last name</td> 
<td>first name</td> 
<td>delete data</td> 
</tr>");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
$id = $row['id'];

echo("<tr>");
        echo("<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>");
        echo("<td>" . $row['lastName'] . "</td>");
        echo("<td>" . $row['firstName'] . "</td>");
        echo("<td> <form action='$self' method='post'> 
                <input type='hidden' name='delete_id value='$id' /> 
                <input type='submit' value='Delete' />  
            </form> 
        </td>
    </tr>");
}
mysql_free_result($result);
echo("</table>");

}
```

However this does not work. Does anyone know why. NOTE: I have left my login credentials out but I am connecting to the database elsewhere in the file.

Comment: Just a side note `name='delete_id` is not well quoted

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Does it give you an error message? Display a blank screen? Print out the information? Not delete when you click on a button? Delete the wrong record?

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause is that your checking for $_POST['Delete'] having not given any of the submit buttons the attribute 'name' of 'Delete'. However, the line you have commented out above should work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into this areas

```
//if(isset($_POST['delete_id']) && (!empty($_POST['delete_id'])))
```

if(isset($_POST['Delete'])){

and

```
<input type='submit' value='Delete' />
```

You should include: `<input type='submit' name="Delete" value='Delete' />`

That should solve the problem.